# Helm update only one property

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

Im using helm to install succesfully components via the following command

```
helm template install/kubernetes/helm/istio --name istio --namespace istio-system  \ --set tracing.enabled=true --set servicegraph.enabled=true \ --set grafana.enabled=true | kubectl apply -f -
```

Now I want to change only one property like

```
--set tracing.enabled=false
```

I try the following with just the field which I need to modify

```
helm template update/kubernetes/helm/istio --name istio --namespace istio-system  \ --set tracing.enabled=flase  | kubectl apply -f -
```

without success, do I miss something ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`helm template` is totally stateless – it reads a Helm chart's configuration and YAML files, and writes out the YAML that results from applying all of the templates.  It has no idea that you've run it before with different options.

The current version of Helm has a cluster-side component called Tiller that keeps track of state like this, and the Istio documentation does have [specific instructions for using Tiller](https://istio.io/docs/setup/kubernetes/install/helm/#option-2-install-with-helm-and-tiller-via-helm-install).  Since there is state kept here, you can do an update like

```
helm upgrade istio \
  install/kubernetes/helm/istio \
  --reuse-values \
  --set tracing.enabled=false
```

Another valid option is to keep your install-time options in a YAML file

```
tracing:
  enabled: true
servicegraph:
  enabled: true
grafana:
  enabled: true
```

And then you can pass those options using Helm's `-f` flag

```
helm template install/kubernetes/helm/istio \
  --name istio \
  -f istio-config.yaml
```

This option also works with `helm install` and `helm upgrade`, and is equivalent to passing all of the `--set` options you specified.

Comment: Thanks, two questions: 1. if Im doing again `helm install` what happen in this case the the previous config  2. is there a way to update specific property in `istio` `without` helm , e.g. if I want to update the `gateways.enabled` to false https://istio.io/docs/reference/config/installation-options/#gateways-options

Comment: The Istio docs suggest you _have_ to use Helm in some form to install it – those config options can affect things like the presence of specific Deployments or ConfigMap keys that would be hard to adjust by hand.  If you've `helm install` once, you need to use `helm upgrade` to change the configuration later.